# Is there a way to remove the "No Results" label from a UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, three20, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a three20 controller that is using the new sdk3 UISearchDisplayController.
I also have a model that is loaded from the network, it seems that no matter what I do the default behavior for the UISearchDisplayController is show "No Results" label.
Is there a way to make it go away and show something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the "No Results" text you need to implement the titleForEmpty method in your TTTableViewDataSource.

```
- (NSString*)titleForEmpty {
  return @"No names found";
}
```

Comment: The thing is that this is not the same. NoData != "No Results" . 
it seems that the No Results comes internally from the Search Controller.

Comment: Ah, yes. I've edited the answer to point out the correct method for this. If you implement titleForEmpty, Three20 will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

search the Three20 source code for the string "No Results" and change it to @"".